# How to rename all columns at once

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe looks like this

```
index brand_spend_kitchen brand_spend_car brand_spend_home
1      3                      5           7
2      2                      5           8
```

The df is more complicated than this, but this example is suffice.
I am hoping to change all column names to `'% spend kitchen', '% spend car', and '% spend home'`.

Instead of using `df.rename(columns = {})` which requires manual input. Is there a more efficient way to change the col names?

Answer (score 2):

You could simply `map()` them to a different name using `.replace()`:

```py
data.columns = list(map(lambda c: '% ' + c.replace('_', ' '), data.columns))
```

To keep the first column (`index`) unchanged:

```py
new_columns = list(map(lambda c: '% ' + c.replace('_', ' '), data.columns[1:]))
data.columns = pd.Index([data.columns[0]] + new_columns)
```

You can also use `data.rename` passing the same `lambda` as above to rename columns. Avoiding renaming the first one can be done by first setting it as index with `data.set_index('index')`.

Comment: I also have a column index which I don't want to change. How do I avoid that

Answer (score 1):

```
df.columns = df.columns.str.replace('.*(spend)_(.*)', r'% \1 \2', regex = True)

df

   index  % spend kitchen  % spend car  % spend home
0      1                3            5             7
1      2                2            5             8
```

Answer (score 0):

the answer depends on if you have a typo or not. I'm going to assume you do not.

you have a list containing a single string `['value1, value2, value3']` (see how this is different from `['value1', 'value2', 'value3']` ). We're going to separate this into a new list, full of individual strings.

```
# grab the first item in the list (the long string)
myString = data.columns[0]
#split it into a list
myList = list(myString.split(', '))
print(myList)
>>>> ['spend_in_home', 'spend_in_kitchen', 'spend_in_tools' ... etc]
```

okay so if that was a typo, no need to do this bit of code, either way, once you have a list that contains several strings, we need to actually manipulate it. It looks like what you want to do is to add '% ' to the beginning of each string, and replace every '_' with a ' '. first lets do the '% '

```
for i in range(len(myList)):
    #current item
    current = myList[i]
    #add our prefix
    current = '% ' + current

    #paste it onto the list
    myList[i] = current

print(myList)
>>>> ['% spend_in_home', '% spend_in_kitchen', '% spend_in_tools']
```

finally, let's add an action in that same for loop to turn the underscores into spaces:

```
for i in range(len(myList)):
    #current item
    current = myList[i]
    #add our prefix
    current = '% ' + current
    #replace all instances of '_' with ' '
    current = current.replace('_', ' ')

    #paste it onto the list
    myList[i] = current

print(myList)
>>>> ['% spend in home', '% spend in kitchen', '% spend in tools']
```

Hope that helps, feel free to clarify if I missed something!

Comment: Edited the question, is there easier way to do this.

Comment: It looks like you fixed your question, you have a list containing several strings, not just one string. All you need to do is run the last block of code that I put in. If you think For Loops are difficult, I would recommend learning them [W3Schools article](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_for_loops.asp), [Youtube Tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=94UHCEmprCY&). They're really not that hard to learn once you start doing a few examples. Otherwise, I would recommend using Marco Bonelli's solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [functions in pd.DataFrame.rename](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rename.html#pandas-dataframe-rename):

```
df = df.set_index('index') # Be sure index is in the index
df_out = df.rename(columns=lambda x: '% '+ ' '.join(x.split('_')[1:]))
df_out = df_out.reset_index() #move index back to columns if desired.
```

Output:

```
   index  % spend kitchen  % spend car  % spend home
0      1                3            5             7
1      2                2            5             8
```

Here we just created a lambda function to do string manipulation.

Answer (score 0):

Rename using a lambda function:

```
df.rename(columns=lambda x: x.replace('brand_','% ').replace('_',' '))

   index  % spend kitchen  % spend car  % spend home
0      1                3            5             7
1      2                2            5             8
```